# Ты знаешь, что делаешь / Он знает, что делает

Tags: лексика, смысл

В известном ролике слова «мама, ты знаешь, что делаешь» как обращение звучат противоестественно, а стало быть, они неуместны. Так ли это?

Обычно, высоко оценивая поступки или свойства человека, говорят в третьем лице: «Он знает, что делает». Напротив, сказанное лично — *ты знаешь, что делаешь* — в глаза человеку, по моему ощущению, никакой интонацией нельзя смягчить из-за скрытой угрозы, предполагаемой или прямой.

Answer (score 4):

Эту фразу обычно говорят, когда не до конца понимают или одобряют чьи-то поступки, но выражают надежду, что всё делается верно.

При этом часто добавляют  слова "я думаю, я надеюсь". Если сказать "я уверен", то тогда это будет **выражение  уважения к лицу и полного доверия к его действиям.**

Получится: **Мама,  (я уверен), ты знаешь, что ты делаешь.**

― **Надеюсь, ты знаешь, что делаешь**, ― поколебавшись, Дмитрий перевел. [Семен Данилюк. Бизнес-класс (2003)]

Муж, узнав о ее очередном приобретении, только сокрушенно качает головой: 
«**Надеюсь, ты знаешь, что делаешь»**. [Марина Каминарская. Дом с привидениями (2002) // «Домовой», 2002.12.04]

― Ну-ну, ― сказал Александр, ― **наверное, ты знаешь, что делаешь…** [Иржи Грошек. Легкий завтрак в тени некрополя (1998)]

Comment: В рекламе нет ни «я уверена», ни второго «ты». И так, конечно, не получается. Но мысль Ваша — когда не до конца понимают или одобряют — хоть и мягко сформулирована, но верна: все цитаты её подтверждают. Особенно вторая, где муж сокрушенно качает головой.